# Reverse proxy with usage monitoring API

Tags: performance, api, monitoring, reverse-proxy, status

I need to configure a reverse proxy and get some status parameters like failures, acess log, usage of resources, storing. I'm looking options like apache and ngyng. Does anybody already used a reverse proxy with an API that offers this performance indicators?

Any tip will be very helpful,

Thanks.